# The button for logging into github in visual studio code isnt there

Tags: github, visual-studio-code

As the title says, i dont know how to describe it further.
How do I get it back??[image]

Answer (score 0):

Use GitHub Desktop app and clone from it ,or from this symbol

[image: git]

Comment: Not the answer I was looking for, but thanks.

Comment: so click on the third symbol in the left side it will ask you to login after click clone

Comment: Not there, it says "No source control providers registered."